# Length measurement of a moving hot deformed bar with a sensor

Tags: sensor

In a hot rolling mill moving deformed bars are cut according to the desired lengths, which sensor is suitable to use for measuring the length of the moving hot bar and sending the instruction to the shear cut to apply the cut, e.g. 40 feet length is desired from a 240 feet long bar, keeping in view the temperature factor.

Comment: What is your definition of "deformed" and "length". Eg. If it's bent in an S shape do you want the linear length of the metal or the length of the S. Also are the moving bars restricted to be moving in a single line or can they be diagonal on a belt... All of these points make a big difference.

Comment: If you are wanting people to "keeping in view the temperature factor", then you need to define what you mean by "hot", as that has a very wide range of values. The only thing we know is that "hot" is below the melting point of the material (which we'd have to guess at, as you didn't specify the material, or conditions).

Comment: You should also specify the precision required, at least approximately, as different methods might be needed to obtain various levels of precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feeding a known material is best done with a drive roller in conjunction with a metering roller.

The two are arranged to "pinch" the material as it passes such that when the material is present the drive roller/material turns the metering roller.

[image]

Metering encoder can be an actual shaft encoder or some sort of hall effect sensor detecting details on the metering roller.

Slipping can be minimized by using an appropriate spring force and if need me adding knurling or other surface "teeth" to the roller.

I'd also use an additional sensor on the tension arm to detect when the stock is in the mechanism.

**Note 1:** Some tweaking can be required to get this to work consistently especially if the uniformity and speed of the material can cause the tension arm to bounce. Your vague indication that the material is somehow "deformed" may make this a non-starter.

**Note 2:** Depending on how hot.. hot is, some adjustment or compensation may be required to compensate for thermal expansion in the metering roller which will take heat from the material. A small change in diameter over 40' in length will add up quickly if the idler is not very large.

Comment: You and your drawings man. xD

Comment: @WesleyLee it's fun :)

Comment: Sir consider the speed of pinch roll is 8 m/s if we use rotary encoder with digital counter will it be useful, how can we calculate the slip?

Comment: @shahzebkhan speed itself is not an issue, slip is only a factor when accelerating and decelerating the idler. You are now adding in new requirements not mentioned in the original question, which was very light in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOVTBy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using a through-beam sensor to detect cut-point of steel stock.*

Use a through-beam sensor positioned 40 feet from the cutter. When the infeed reaches the sensor then actuate the cutters.

Comment: While this is a reasonable methodology, it doesn't address the environmental concerns (i.e. temperature) which the OP mentioned.

Comment: Sure it does. Non-contact optical solution: break the beam and operate the shears. Most through-beam industrial sensors will operate in this environment unless the steel is so hot that the IR and visible light drive the receiver into saturation. In that case a laser version would probably do the trick.

Comment: While a non-contact optical solution does have significant benefits with respect to thermal isolation, it doesn't guarantee no issues, particularly without specifying separation distances from the material, type of TX/RX devices, etc. It also introduces issues such as choosing a wavelength which is not affected by ambient conditions and/or the material being detected, etc. I'm not saying that this is a bad choice, just one that's presented as a strawman with a significant amount of information to fill in. In part, this is because the OP hasn't specified much detail about the problem.

Comment: What you've commented above is largely the additional information/caveats I would have expected to see in your answer, as the OP hasn't given enough information to provide a detailed answer. You might want to also mention that a laser would provide additional precision, if that's a criteria.

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't think the question deserved the work. Feel free to post your own version ...

Comment: You've got a point regarding the amount of work the question deserves. It's really not sufficiently formed to be able to provide much more than possible directions to go in, along with stating expected issues.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the rotation of one of the rollers can be used : avoids any temperature issue , but slip may be a factor...